Experiencing error 400 - Dialogflow Messenger Integration (BotNotStartedException)
Error Received:
com.google.dialogflow.bots.common.exceptions.BotWasNotStartedException: Code 400: The user must be an administrator, editor, or moderator of the page in order to impersonate it. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.
Context (Image shows Facebook Messenger Integration with Dialogflow Error):

Steps taken to resolve:

Requested to be given Administrator on the corresponding page
Disabling Persistent Menu
Disabled Two-Way Authentication

